# What does " she seemed no more put out than she would be by a light rain." means?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm reading a Light Novel called "Overlord" and in a fight scene the author is describing a character action and reaction to the enemy's attacks,being one of them,this sentence " **she seemed no more put out than she would be by a light rain.**"

I can't understand what the author means by that, is it a poetical sentence or something like that?

Comment: Are you personally bothered by light rain when you are out walking?

Comment: Is it _put out_ that puzzles you? One of its meanings is _annoyed or upset_.

Comment: Entry 4.1 in this [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/put_out)

Answer (score 2):

To be *put out* means to be inconvenienced or caused discomfort.

[Merriam-Webster put out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20out)

5.a : disconcert, embarrass
b : annoy, irritate
c : inconvenience

"no more put out than by a light rain" means that she was not caused more discomfort by the attacks than she would be by a light rain. The attacks were a minor inconvenience.